# What is wrong with the constructor?

Tags: java

I am supposed to design an inventory system that will store specific products using the provided Driver class named ProductTester to test my program. But for some reason, it doesn't work. When I look at the problem on the program, it states that I'm using the wrong data type on the constructor in ProductTester. But from what I see, I think I'm using it correctly?

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDRMa.png)

On the log, I couldn't really understand the problem, but the description states:

'CD(java.lang.String, double, int, int, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)' in 'Project10.CD' cannot be applied to '(int, java.lang.String, int, double, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)'

'CD(java.lang.String, double, int, int, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)' in 'Project10.CD' cannot be applied to '(int, java.lang.String, int, double, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)'

'CD(java.lang.String, double, int, int, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)' in 'Project10.CD' cannot be applied to '(int, java.lang.String, int, double, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)'

Sorry, I was only able to provide you with partial of the code because I wasn't able to finish the other part. So please ignore some of the parts that have missing details. For example DVD.

```
public class Product {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean active = true;

    public Product(int number, String name, double price, int quantity) {
        setNumber(number);
        setName(name);
        setProductPrice(price);
        setQtyInStock(quantity);
    }

    public int getNumber() { return number; }
    public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public double getProductPrice() { return price; }
    public void setProductPrice(double price) { this.price = price; }

    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public void setQtyInStock(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }

    public void addToInventory(int quantity) { this.quantity += quantity; }
    public void deductFromInventory(int quantity) { if (!(this.quantity - quantity < 0)) this.quantity -= quantity; }

    public void setActive(boolean active) { this.active = active; }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nItem Number: " + getNumber() + "\nName: " + getName() + "\nQuantity in Stock: " + getQuantity()
                + "\nPrice: " + getProductPrice() + "\nStock Value: " + (quantity * price) + "\nProduct Status: "
                + (this.active?"Active" : "Discontinued");
    }
}    


class CD extends Product {
        private String artist;
        private int numOfSongs;
        private String label;
        private boolean active = true;
    
        public CD(String name, double price, int quantity, int number, String artist, int numOfSongs, String label) {
            super(number, name, price, quantity);
            setArtist(artist);
            setNumberOfSongs(numOfSongs);
            setLabel(label);
        }
    
        public String getArtist() { return this.artist; }
        public void setArtist(String artist) { this.artist = artist; }
    
    public int getNumberOfSongs() { return this.numOfSongs; }
    public void setNumberOfSongs(int numOfSongs) { this.numOfSongs = numOfSongs; }

    public String getLabel() { return this.label; }
    public void setLabel(String label) { this.label = label; }

    public String toString() { // Overriding the toString method to display it's own stuff
        return "\nItem Number: " + getNumber() + "\nName: " + getName() + "\nArtist: " + getArtist()
                + "\nSongs on Album: " + getNumberOfSongs() + "\nRecord Label: " + getLabel() + "\nQuantity in Stock: " + getQuantity()
                + "\nPrice:" + getProductPrice() + "\nStock Value: " + (getQuantity() * getProductPrice())
                + "\nProduct Status: " + (this.active ? "Active" : "Discontinued");
    }
}



import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSize, menuChoice;

        maxSize = getNumProducts(in);
        if(maxSize == 0) {
            //Display a no products message if zero is entered
            System.out.println("No products required!");
        }else {
            Product[] products = new Product[maxSize];
            addToInventory(products, in);
            do {
                menuChoice = getMenuOption(in);
                executeMenuChoice(menuChoice, products, in);
            }while(menuChoice != 0);
        }//endif
    }//end method main

    static void executeMenuChoice(int choice, Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("View Product List");
                displayInventory(products);
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Add Stock");
                addInventory(products, in);
                break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Deduct Stock");
                deductInventory(products, in);
                break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Discontinue Stock");
                discontinueInventory(products, in);
                break;
        }//end switch
    }//end method executeMenuChoice

    static void discontinueInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        int productChoice;

        productChoice = getProductNumber(products, in);
        products[productChoice].setActive(false);
    }//end method deductInventory


    static void deductInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        int productChoice;
        int updateValue = -1;
        productChoice = getProductNumber(products, in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("How many products do you want to deduct? ");
                updateValue = in.nextInt();
                if(updateValue <0)
                    System.out.println("Please only enter positive values to deduct stock");
                //endif
                if(updateValue > products[productChoice].getQuantity())
                    System.out.println("THere is not enough stock to remove that amount, only "
                            + products[productChoice].getQuantity() + " left!");
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
            }
        }while(updateValue < 0 ||updateValue > products[productChoice].getQuantity());

        products[productChoice].deductFromInventory(updateValue);
    }//end method deductInventory

    static void addInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        int productChoice;
        int updateValue = -1;
        productChoice = getProductNumber(products, in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("How many products do you want to add? ");
                updateValue = in.nextInt();
                if(updateValue <0)
                    System.out.println("Please only enter positive values to add stock");
                //endif
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
            }
        }while(updateValue < 0);

        products[productChoice].addToInventory(updateValue);
    }//end method addInventory

    static int getProductNumber(Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        int productChoice = -1;
        //display the contents of the products array
        for(int i = 0; i< products.length; i++)
            System.out.println(i + " : " + products[i].getName());

        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Please enter the item number of the product you want to update: ");
                productChoice = in.nextInt();
                if(productChoice < 0 || productChoice > products.length -1)
                    System.out.println("Please only enter values between 0 and "
                            + (products.length -1));
                //endif
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
            }
        }while(productChoice < 0 || productChoice > products.length -1);

        return productChoice;
    }//end method getProductNumber

    static int getMenuOption(Scanner in) {
        int menuOption = -1;

        //display the menu until a valid input is provided
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("\n\n1. View Inventory\n2. Add Stock\n3. Deduct Stock\n"
                        + "4. Discontinue Product\n0. Exit");
                System.out.print("Please enter a menu option: ");
                menuOption = in.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
            }
        }while(menuOption < 0 || menuOption > 4);

        //return the valid input from the user
        return menuOption;
    }//end method getMenuOption

    static int getNumProducts(Scanner in) {
        int maxSize= -1;

        //prompt the user until they enter a number >= zero
        do {
            try{
                //display prompt to user
                System.out.println("Enter the number of products you would like to add.");
                System.out.print("Enter 0 (zero) if you do not wish to add products: ");
                //assume that the user enters a valid
                maxSize = in.nextInt();
                if(maxSize < 0)
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Value entered");
                //endif
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
            }
        }while(maxSize < 0);

        //returns the valid value entered by the user
        return maxSize;

    }//end method getNUmProducts

    static void addToInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in) {
        //create local variables
        int stockChoice = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            //display the menu until a valid input is provided
            do {
                try {
                    //ask the user to enter the product information
                    System.out.println("\n1: CD\n2: DVD");
                    System.out.print("Please enter the product type: ");
                    stockChoice = in.nextInt();
                    if(stockChoice < 1 || stockChoice > 2)
                        System.out.println("Only numbers 1 or 2 allowed!");
                    //endif
                }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect data type entered!");
                    in.nextLine();
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    in.nextLine();
                }
            }while(stockChoice < 1 || stockChoice > 2);
            if(stockChoice == 1)
                addCDToInventory(products, in, i);
            else
                addDVDToInventory(products, in, i);
        }
    }//end method addToInventory

    static void addCDToInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in, int i) {
        //create local variables
        int number;
        String name;
        int quantity;
        double price;
        String artist;
        int numOfSongs;
        String label;

        //clear the input buffer
        in.nextLine();
        //ask the user to enter the product information
        System.out.print("\n\nPlease enter the CD name: ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the artist name: ");
        artist = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the record label name: ");
        label = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of songs: ");
        numOfSongs = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of stock for this product: ");
        quantity = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the price for this product: ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter the item number: ");
        number = in.nextInt();
        //create a CD product object and store it in the products array
        products[i] = new CD( number, name, quantity, price, artist, numOfSongs, label);
    }//end method addCDToInventory

    static void addDVDToInventory(Product[] products, Scanner in, int i) {
        //create local variables
        int number;
        String name;
        int quantity;
        double price;
        int length;
        int rating;
        String studio;

        //clear the input buffer
        in.nextLine();
        //ask the user to enter the product information
        System.out.print("\n\nPlease enter the DVD name: ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the film studio name: ");
        studio = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the age rating: ");
        rating = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the length in minutes: ");
        length = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of stock for this product: ");
        quantity = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the price for this product: ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter the item number: ");
        number = in.nextInt();
        //create a DVD product object and store it in the products array
        products[i] = new DVD(number, name, quantity, price, length, rating, studio);
    }//end method addDVDToInventory

    static void displayInventory(Product[] products) {
        //display the contents of the products array
        for(Product product: products)
            System.out.println(product);
    }//end method displayInventory
}//end class ProductTaster
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Parameter order matters. Check the order of parameters in your constructor declaration against what you are passing in when you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to pass in unexpected parameters.

The constructor of your CD class looks like this:

```
  public CD(String name, double price, int quantity, int number, String artist, int numOfSongs, String label) {
        super(number, name, price, quantity);
        setArtist(artist);
        setNumberOfSongs(numOfSongs);
        setLabel(label);
    }
```

So it expects:

```
String name, double price, int quantity, int number, String artist, int numOfSongs, String label
```

but you are passing in:

```
int number, String name, int quantity, double price, String artist, int numOfSongs, String label
```

To fix this, change the constructor to take in the correct parameters you want.

Comment: Ohhhhh my god! Thank you very much! This problem never happened to me so it was very confusing. Again, thank you very much!